# PEAR's mail queue alternative?

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm looking for a good mass mailing library for PHP. Everything seems to point to Pear's mail_queue, but I was wondering if there are any alternatives? I need something that can:

1. Manage multiple smtp servers, each with their own per hour limit
2. Send HTML emails
3. Do all of this as fast as possible?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at http://swiftmailer.org ?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked through the Swift Mailer site and it looks like in order to limit messages per hour/minute, you use the Throttler Plugin (http://swiftmailer.org/docs/throttler-plugin).  I have PHP Mail (PEAR package) working on my web app, but I too am looking for something to throttle the message rate as my web host restricts me to 1 email per minute.  I like the documentation on Swift Mailer's site, which is way better than the documentation on the Mail_Queue site (http://pear.php.net/manual/zh/package.mail.mail-queue.mail-queue.tutorial.php).

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.